# Alter query string param based off of checkboxes in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm able to successfully run this code when a box is checked to filter results:

```
changeCheck = (index, acronym) => {
        if(!this.state.checkedLeagues.includes(acronym)){
            this.state.checkedLeagues.push(acronym)
        } else {
            this.setState({checkedLeagues: this.state.checkedLeagues.filter(v => { return v !== acronym})})
        }
        this.state.checked[index] = !this.state.checked[index]
        this.setState({ checked: this.state.checked })




        queryString = []

        console.log('newLeagues', newLeagues)

        this.state.checkedLeagues.map(
            (v, i) => {
                if(queryString.length < 1) {
                    queryString.push(`?league=${v}`)
                } else if (queryString.length >= 1 ) {
                    queryString.push(`&league=${v}`)
                }
            }
        )

        // console.log(queryString.join(''))

        axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/reports${queryString.join('')}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.props.loadCards(response.data)
                })
    }
```

The issue comes when a box is unchecked.

I need a way to remove the box that was unchecked from queryString if it already exists in this.state.checked.

The value that is checked or unchecked is passed in on onPress/onClick through acronym.

Edit:

As an example:
If this.state.checkedLeagues is an array of leagues ['NBA', 'NFL'], I only want to set those as query string paramaters in the axios get request.

If I set the checkedLeagues to ['NBA', 'NFL'], it works. But when I uncheck it does not; lets say I uncheck 'NBA' (when I say uncheck, I mean remove from the queryString), it does not, because I do not have a mechanism remove the unchecked box from queryString.

Comment: Try to give an example for what you want to do please

Comment: @Idan I just added an edit with an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.state = {
        checkList: [],
    };

checkInvoice = (index) => {
    const { checkList } = this.state
    const newCheckList = checkList;
    const indexElem = newCheckList.indexOf(index);
    if (indexElem > -1) {
        newCheckList.splice(indexElem, 1);
    } else {
        newCheckList.push(index);
    } 
    this.setState({ checkList: newCheckList })
};
```

From here you need to connect to your code and query...
tell me if it ok